# read static files on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, web, stream

I'm trying to build my own static web server through module NET (with sockets),
and i want to write response for text files(html,js,css...) and response for img files(jpg,gif....),

I tried to do it with createReadStream and readFile , and it works, but it stuck on loading all the time,
and the picture does not work sometimes...

```
FS.stat(fileSystemAddress + request.fileName, function (err, stat) {
    if (err) {
        // Error handling
    } else {
        if (typeImg[request.fileType] != undefined) {
            response.headers['Content-Length'] = stat.size;
            response.headers['Content-Type'] = typeImg[request.fileType];
            response.writeImg(200);
            var fileStream = FS.createReadStream(fileSystemAddress + request.fileName);
            fileStream.pipe(response.socket, {
                end: false
            });
        }
    }
});

if (typeFile[request.fileType] != undefined) {
    FS.readFile(fileSystemAddress + request.fileName, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            // Error handling
        } else {
            response.headers['Content-Length'] = data.length;
            response.headers['Content-Type'] = typeFile[request.fileType];
            response.writeFile(200,data);
        }
    });
}
```

and the writeFile,writeImg methods:

```
this.writeImg = function (code) {
    this.status(code);
    this.title = that.protocol + "/" + that.httpVersion + " " + that.statusCode.name + " " + that.statusCode.message  + "\r\n";
    this.socket.write(that.title + that.responseTime + "Content-Type:" + that.headers["Content-Type"] + "\r\n" + "Content-Length: " + that.headers["Content-Length"]   + "\r\n"  + "\r\n");
}
this.writeFile = function(code,body){
    this.status(code);
    this.title = that.protocol + "/" + that.httpVersion + " " + that.statusCode.name + " " + that.statusCode.message  + "\r\n";
    console.log(that.title + that.responseTime + "Content-Type:" + that.headers["Content-Type"] + "\r\n" + "Content-Length: " + that.headers["Content-Length"]   + "\r\n"  + body);
    this.socket.write(that.title + that.responseTime + "Content-Type:" + that.headers["Content-Type"] + "\r\n" + "Content-Length: " + that.headers["Content-Length"]   + "\r\n"  + "\r\n" + body);
}
```

any idea what can i do in order to manage files and images without the web to stuck on loading (its local server by the way, so it should work fast)?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another thread here recently suggested http://expressjs.com/, an application framework on top of node.js which handles not only the lookup of the local resources but also provides filter implementations (they call it middleware) for authentication, cache headers, and many other things.

Comment: I know about express, but as i said, i'm trying to build my own static web server through module NET :) thanks.